# Run update script from select result for each row

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a table with thousands scripts that I would like to run them in a while loop, but the query result doesn't have an ID column that can use to count, do you know?

There is only on column with the scripts. See some sample data:

```
UPDATE CAT_SP_03476811013725_01_2009 SET COD_LEGAL = '' WHERE ISNULL(PRODUTO_EXCLUIDO,'') <> 'S' 
UPDATE CAT_SP_03476811013725_02_2009 SET COD_LEGAL = '' WHERE ISNULL(PRODUTO_EXCLUIDO,'') <> 'S' 
UPDATE CAT_SP_03476811013725_03_2009 SET COD_LEGAL = '' WHERE ISNULL(PRODUTO_EXCLUIDO,'') <> 'S'
```

I need to run each script from each row in a store procedure, but I don't know how to do it and I wouldn't like to copy the result and past them in the query editor because there are thousands records in dozen of tables, so, can someone help me with some example of store procedure to reach out this goal?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As a start, my recommendation is to add a key column to the table. This way at least you know which script you are running.

Answer (score 0):

Following the Seaport recommendation, I create this sp:

```
CREATE TABLE #tabscrdia (id int identity(1,1), script varchar(255))

--Insere os dados desejados na tabela temporária recem criada
INSERT INTO #tabscrdia 
    SELECT
        CONCAT('UPDATE ', [name], ' SET COD_LEGAL = '''' WHERE ISNULL(PRODUTO_EXCLUIDO,'''') <> ''S'' AND TIPO_OPERACAO = ''E'' AND cenario = ''10'' AND COD_LEGAL <> ''''  AND DESCARTE IS NULL') Query
    FROM sys.tables
    WHERE ([name] like 'CAT_SP_%%_2009' 
        OR [name] like 'CAT_SP_%%_2010' 
        OR [name] like 'CAT_SP_%%_2011' 
        OR [name] like 'CAT_SP_%%_2012' 
        OR [name] like 'CAT_SP_%%_2013' 
        OR [name] like 'CAT_SP_%%_2014') 
        AND [name] not in ('CAT_SP_03476811010033_06_2009', 'CAT_SP_03476811010033_07_2010', 'CAT_SP_03476811012249_03_2012')
        order by substring(name,26,4), substring(name,8,14), substring(name,23,2)

--Cria as variáveis desejadas
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @script VARCHAR(255)
SET @count = 1

--Cria um looping para realizar a ação desejada para cada linha da tabela temporária    
WHILE @count <= (select max(id) from #tabscrdia)

BEGIN
    DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(255)

    --Atribui o script recuperado à variável @script
    SET @cmd = 'select [@script] = script from #tabscrdia where id = [@count]'

    --Transforma o script recuperado em um comando
    SET @cmd = replace(@cmd,'@script',@script)

    --Executa o comando (descomentar após testar de print e comentar teste de print)
    PRINT @cmd
    --exec sp_executesql @cmd

    --Incrementa o contador
    SET @count = @count + 1

END

--Deleta a tabela temporária
drop table #tabscrdia
```

But is is not showing the scripts that I want to run.

What is wrong that? I'm not expert in SQL. Can somebody else give me a north?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue replacing this

```
SET @cmd = 'select [@script] = script from #tabscrdia where id = [@count]'
```

for this

```
SET @cmd = (select script from #tabscrdia where id = @count)
```

Thanks very much